# Blender rendered image black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, image

I'm trying to render an imported obj mesh file. I think I could successfully put the object in the field of view of active camera. But while rendering it doesn't show anything but a black image. I've attached the screenshot of the blender (In the attached image, I've intentionally black out a portion of the object).

[image: Blender image]

Comment: Do you have a lamp in the scene?

Comment: Your lamp Is disabled in the render, look in the top right corner of your screen and click on the disabled camera icon.

Comment: As @Denis pointed out your light is disabled, but you are in solid shading mode and all I can see is wireframe,  could it be that you have no faces in your object?

Comment: @Denis Care to add that as an answer?

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable suggestions. Now my problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your image it appears that your light source is excluded from the render. In the outliner in the top right of your screen, enable your lamp rendering by clicking on the grayed out camera icon.

[image]